# Constraint on Linq to Entities Include

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a message table that self joins to itself where Message.ID == Message.Parent. So I have 1 Message with several ChildMessages. This is set up nicely with a Navigation property.

The code is currently:

```
var message = from m in soe.Messages.Include("ChildMessages")
              where m.ID == id
              && m.IsActive
              select m;
return message.FirstOrDefault();
```

What I really want is to only return 1 Message (that is equal to a particular ID and isActive) with all of its Active ChildMessages and I want to do it in one call to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded this is not possible in Entity framework.

A work around would be to return an anonymous type that satisfies the constraint. E.g.

```
var message = from m in soe.Messages
              where m.ID == id
              && m.IsActive
              select
                  new
                  {
                      Message = m,
                      ChildMessages = m.ChildMessages.Where(c => c.IsActive)
                  };
return message.FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for 4.0 (I'm not sure if it will work on 3.5, i hadn't check).

First, set your entities model `Lazy Loading Enabled` property to `false`. Note that as a result you will lose the references auto-loading.

Next, try this code:

```
var message = soe.Messages
    .Where(m => (m.ID == id || m.ParentId == id) && m.IsActive)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

The EF will resolve the parent-child references, and will not load other child references unless an explicit request will be made (like `Include` or `Load`). Notice that you must iterate over the `Where` results using `AsEnumerable` or otherwise they won't load.

Comment: but that isn't putting a constraint on the child messages. I want to put something like where m.ChildMessages.IsActive. But ChildMessages is a collection so it wont work.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. That's an excellent question. Check my new answer.

Comment: I do want the ChildMessages populated though (but only the active ones). Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: I didn't fully understood your last comment. Does my solution satisfy your requirements? The result of the above code will get you the requested message, with it's active child messages, in one trip to the DB.

Comment: Really interesting idea. It almost worked too. You can have multiple children per parent message this only returns one parent with one child. Not sure I'm happy about lack of lazy loading option either. +1 for goo idea though